# What options are there for reviewing photographs on an iPad

Tags: software, photo-editing, ipad

I am a mediocre photographer, so I take lots of photos and delete most of them.

I thought I would be able to load the photos on to the iPad and review and delete them when convenient, but you can't delete the photos on the iPad from the iPad, except for the 'saved photos', which means I can't use folders.

What other options are there that would allow me to load or access the original photos from the iPad and delete the ones I don't want to keep

**Update:**

I do not have the camera connection kit, I'd prefer an option that just used the iPad as is, though I'd buy one if it was necessary

Comment: Are you referring to loading them using the iPad Camera Connection Kit? If so, are you unable to delete the JPEG preview or the RAW image the JPEG was rendered from?

Comment: Clarification: are you trying to delete files off of the iPad itself, or off of a memory card that you have in the camera connection kit dongle?

Comment: Hrm, I smell a good App idea :D

Comment: Does anyone know if the Camera Connection Kit will allow him to delete photos though? I am curious.

Comment: Don't bring your question sayin you're a 'mediocre' photographer. Have some more self confidence. All of use delete a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option I've found is to use dropbox. 
Copy the original photos into a dropbox folder. The photos can be scanned through nearly as quickly as the photos app, and it is possible to delete the photos without touching the originals

Comment: Nearly two years on and dropbox is still the only straightforward solution that allows me to delete photos from a set of photos

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Photoshop.com Mobile app?

Comment: This looks like a nice app for some basic editing, but you cannot delete the photos from the albums. Also edits are saved back to the saved photo album, so any pics you edit would have to be copied manually after the next sync

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/is-it-possible-to-shoot-tethered-using-an-ipad). In this I have suggest using a [eye-fi](http://uk.eye.fi/) card and the [free app](http://www.eye.fi/products/iphone) to display them on the iPad. Others have other suggested other solutions that may help you.

Comment: That looks a clever device, but I can't find any mention of delete. It is the delete bit that is key to trashing the rubbish shots

Comment: I am not sure about delete, have not used it myself maybe another user may know