# Is it possible to shoot tethered using an iPad?

Tags: tethering, ipad

I would love to use my iPad as a tethering device for instant review but I can't see how to set it up.

I have a nasty suspicion that it's not possible.

Please tell me that I'm wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an [Eye-Fi Pro Card](http://www.eye.fi/products/prox2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1286450251&sr=8-1) and an Application on the iPad (or iPhone or Andriod phone or laptop ect.) to read it.

There are a few options for an App. There is the FREE [eye-fi iPhone app](http://www.eye.fi/products/iphone) or you could have a look at [Shutter Snitch](http://lifehacker.com/5636979/how-to-take-wireless-photos-with-your-dslr-and-ios-device) App which is relativity cheap.

I have not used this approach myself so I cannot say if it is any good however it might do what you want.

Comment: Update with more links on same concept.

Comment: More detail here: http://jesserosten.com/2010/wireless-tethering-to-ipad

Comment: Sigh.  Eye-fi iPhone application not available in a non-free version for those without a Eye-fi card.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 4):

There is a description [here](http://brentbat.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/ipad/) that shows how you can do this, but it seems a bit of a convoluted solution. I don't there is (currently) anything that allows you to link an iPad to a WiFi enabled DSLR directly. But I certainly wouldn't rule it out from ever happening.

Comment: +1 Not a bad solution... but if I have to take a laptop with me, then I might as well just use the laptop!  Still, it's inventive!  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3):

There was an episode of TWIP that discussed an iPad Camera Connection Kit.
[TWiP Episode #166](http://www.thisweekinphoto.com/twip-166-photographers-are-not-terrorists/)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check this out.  I stopped listenning to TWIP a while ago - perhaps I should start again!  :)